# Share a device-specific URL with Facebook Messenger

Tags: ios, facebook, url, share, facebook-messenger

I generated a device-specific URL with [smartURL](https://manage.smarturl.it/) (Link to Google Play Store for Android App Version and Apple App Store for iOS App Version).

I have a problem with sharing my device-specific URL with Facebook Messenger. When I share the device-specific URL with Facebook Messenger  from a Android device to a iOS device, then by clicking on the link it opens the Apple App Store on the iOS Device.

**But when I clicking on the thumbnail image, then it opens the Android Google Play Store on iOS Device.** This seems to be a problem with the Canonical URL. For URL Debugging: [Open Graph Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/)

How can I fix this problem? Can I share a url with Facebook Messenger without thumbnail?

Or is there another way to share a device-specific store-link, without any problems with the Facebook Messenger?

Comment: Have you looked into https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks?

Comment: Thanks @corvuszero! Can I add a parameter like a player id on my Facebook App Link? I need the player id from sender on the receiver side.

Comment: My understanding is yes, you can, and then use that in your app on however way you want. I would definitely dig into the documentation to see how to do this.